# Strange message during the Linux boot caused by udev

Tags: linux, debian, udev, debian-wheezy

When Debian Wheezy, testing version, is booting a strange message appears:

```
udevd[336] timeout usb_id--export /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-2.2/1-1.2:1.0 video4linux/ [502]
```

After this message, another message is displayed that loops for 120 secs:

```
udevd[337] killing /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-2.2/1-1.2:1.0 video4linux/ [502]
```

When it finishes looping, Debian starts normally and nothing seems to be "broken". I also killed the loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to break the loop and the system doesn't give any problem.

It seems that also there's an error on `/sbin/modprobe -b` blacklist

I posted the dmesg log after the comand

```
$ dmesg | grep uvc
[    9.016436] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 UVC VGA WebCam (13d3:5710)

[    9.023046] Modules linked in: uvcvideo(+) videodev arc4 media v4l2_compat_ioctl32 joydev snd_hda_intel(+) snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm nouveau iwlagn snd_seq mac80211 snd_timer snd_seq_device ttm snd cfg80211 asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap pci_hotplug mxm_wmi soundcore i915 pcspkr snd_page_alloc i2c_i801 drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit video wmi ac psmouse serio_raw battery rfkill power_supply evdev i2c_core button processor ext4 mbcache jbd2 crc16 sg sr_mod sd_mod cdrom crc_t10dif ahci libahci libata scsi_mod r8169 mii xhci_hcd ehci_hcd usbcore thermal thermal_sys [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]

[    9.024099]  [<ffffffffa040cfb1>] ? uvc_mc_register_entities+0x160/0x1eb [uvcvideo]

[   9.024135]  [<ffffffffa0407793>] ? uvc_probe+0x1ee7/0x1f18 [uvcvideo]

[    9.026883]  [<ffffffffa041601b>] ? uvc_init+0x1b/0x1000 [uvcvideo]
```

Does anyone know a possible answer? Is this a problem with camera driver??

**EDIT:**

in my */var/log/boot* i have this message for udev:

> startpar: service(s) returned failure: udev ... ^[[31mfailed!^[[39;49m

Comment: I try to put the line
"uvcvideo"
in /etc/modules
but the system boot goes in an infinite loop!
I don't know how risolve it!!